# collection_select method gives error in Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2, form-helpers

I have a Model called Category and other Model Product. They have has_many and belongs_to relation. 
But code in my view

```
    <p><%= f.collection_select(:product, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name)%>
```

is giving me

```
 undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol
```

Any clue what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Chances are you have something like this:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
```

Because `f` is already tied to `product`, you don't need to include it as your first argument, so it should just be:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
```

Or, you could not use `f.`:

```
<%= collection_select :product, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
```

Comment: That helped. Thank you. Could you explain conceptually what was wrong there. Help Appreciated.

Comment: Using form_for eliminates the need to put `:product` on every fields. Read this, it talks about how it expands the `f.` part: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: I was encountering this error as I tried to implement a custom form_helper for use with Twitter Bootstrap. I'm kind of new to Rails, and when I found your answer, it really opened my eyes. Thanks, to you, problem fixed! Many, many, thanks!!