# implement grouped_collection_select not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, grouped-collection-select

I want dropdown in User sign up form which will set the user role which belongs to a department. Here is are models

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles

end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :roles
end
```

And in the registration form i am trying this:

```
=form.grouped_collection_select(:user, :role_id, @departments, :roles, :title, :id,:title)
```

This produces error
**undefined method `merge' for :title:Symbol**

Department and Role both models contain "title"

I don't know where i am lacking

Comment: just try without value `=form.grouped_collection_select :user, :role_id, @departments, :roles, :title, :id, :title`

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev oh i just tried without value. see the edit

Comment: with using value it gives undefined method user and without value the mentioned error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine if you removed the **form** from form.grouped_collection_select

OR

If you really need it and the form is already referring to a user form builder then you can skip the first argument of :user passed to the grouped_collection_from method

Using any form builder to initiate a helper method like (select,collection, grouped_collection, ...etc) will automatically passes its `object` to the helper and the helper will expect arguments starting after the `object` parameter.

Check this SO question: [collection_select method gives error in Rails 3.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147069/collection-select-method-gives-error-in-rails-3-1-1)