# Cant add a second dropdown in my form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, drop-down-menu

I am trying to add a second dropdown menu to a form in my app. I have copied the code from the first drop down and changed the values to match the class I am trying to pull values from. When I remove the second drop down, the app runs smoothly, it is the second menu that returns an error.

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Providers
```

If i change 'Providers.order' to 'Provider.order' in my code, it returns this error:

```
undefined method `provider_id' for #<Bill:0x007fbf62544ee8>
```

Here is my code in the form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <!-- Drop Down menu for categories -->
    <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <!-- Drop Down menu for providers -->
    <%= f.label :provider_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :provider_id, Providers.order(:name), :id, :name%>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a model named Provider?

Comment: Yes. I have a whole mvc for provider that references to categories.

Comment: The first error is because you have Providers instead of Provider. What are the relationships you have between your models?

Comment: A bill:
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :provider
  has_many :reminders
------
A category:
   has_many :bills
   has_many :providers
-------
A Provider:
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :bill

Comment: It returns the error "undefined method provider_id for #<#<Class:0x007fd6d1216290>:0x007fd6d53c4728>"  A little different than the other error. this one refers to class and not bill like the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="field">
  <!-- Drop Down menu for providers -->
  <%= label :provider %><br>
  <%= collection_select :provider, :provider_id, Provider.order(:name).all, :id, :name%>
</div>
```

Comment: That returns the first of the two error "uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Providers" and if i change it to 'Provider.order', it returns "undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol"

Comment: See edit. Try removing "f.", per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147069/collection-select-method-gives-error-in-rails-3-1-1